# C program works from the command line but not from Python script?

Tags: c, string, python-2.7, hash, machine-learning

**Updated with whole python script.**

Ok, so I am taking a Machine Learning course at Coursera.org and I want to see what some of these types of algorithmns can do with encryption techniques and test to see if it is possible to break an encryption say with a Neural Network. First I need to create a hash table for a training set, but I am having troubles with C string arrays, args, and Python passing strings as args to a C program.

Here is my lil C program called hashpipe

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #define __USE_GNU
    #include <crypt.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int main(int argc, char** argv){
            char * salt = argv[2];
            struct crypt_data data;
            data.initialized = 0;
            char * result = crypt_r(argv[1], id, &data);
            printf("%s\n", result);
            return 0 // This was the bugger!!! I forgot it!!!
    }
```

And the Python script that calls this little program... Note that I am not sure if I use `exit` correctly.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python2.7

    import sys, random, subprocess

    pathToWL = str(sys.argv[1]) #Path to WordList
    pathForHT = str(sys.argv[2]) #Path to create Hash Table; no, its not smokable
    mId = str(sys.argv[3]) #id for use with crypt_r() see 'man 3 crypt_r'

    SaltCharSet = str("a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9")
    SaltCharSet = SaltCharSet.split(" ")

    try:
        fdWL = open(pathToWL, 'r')
    except:
        print "Could not open wordlist file."
        exit()

    try:
        fdHT = open(pathForHT, 'a')
    except:
        print "Could not open file for hash table"
        fdWL.close()
        exit()

    #We have our wordlist now step through the thing and start generating hashes.

    toStop = False
    cursor = 0 #Use the cursor later once this program evolves

    while(not toStop):
        try:
            ln = str(fdWL.readline())
        except:
            toStop = True
            continue
        ln = ln.strip("\n")
        if len(ln) < 6:
            continue
        # create random salts
        # send ln, id, and salts to hashpipe
        salt = []
        lenOfSalt = random.randint(6,16)
        while(len(salt) < lenOfSalt + 1):
            aORn = random.randint(0,1)
            if aORn == 0:# Its a letter
               uORl = random.randint(0,1)
                if uORl == 0:
                    salt.append(SaltCharSet[(random.randint(0,25))].upper())
                elif uORl == 1:
                    salt.append(SaltCharSet[(random.randint(0,25))].lower())
                else:
                    print "Random Int 'uORl' out of bounds"
                    fdHT.close()
                    fdWL.close()
                    toStop = True
                    exit() # I don't know what happened
                    break #in case exit() fails or is used incorrectly

            elif aORn == 1:# Its a number
                salt.append(SaltCharSet[(random.randint(26, 35))])
            else:
                print "Random Int 'aORn' out of bounds"
                fdHT.close()
                fdWL.close()
                toStop = True
                exit() # I don't know what happened
                break #in case exit() fails or is used incorrectly
        #Generated Salt
        salt = "".join(salt)
        wholeArg2 = str("$"+mId+"$"+salt)
        try:
            mHash = str(subprocess.check_output(["hashpipe", ln, wholeArg2]))
        except:
            print " error getting hash"
            #Clean-up
            fdHT.close()
            fdWL.close()
            toStop = True
            exit()
            break
        #Generated hash, now write it to the fdHT file
        print str(ln+" "+wholeArg2+"\t"+mHash)
        fdHT.write(str(ln+"\t"+mHash+"\n"))
        cursor = fdWL.tell()

    fdHT.close()
    fdWL.close()

    return 0 #Yes, I forgot it here too, probably why my script never ended! LOL!!! so simple!!!
```

I have been changing this part heavily and nothing works, whats the deal? It works on the command line but not from python. For instance the `strip('\0')` and `str(r"$")` are some modification I recently made but still didn't work. Maybe I'll just write a bash script instead...

Note, that the compiled C program does what it should on the cmd-line.

Comment: Please give sample inputs to make your Python example reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

DOH!
I needed to return 0 in my C program. Its working now just to let you know. Creating my first hash table of sorts :)